# Create a web page to show information from ServiceNow

Tags: rest, html, servicenow

I want to create a web page (like a dashboard) to show information from ServiceNow like :

1. Number of customers in Europe region
2. Number of incidents
3. Number of open incidents
4. Number of close incidents

etc

Can you please suggest how should I proceed on this?(I know Java and have idea about Rest)

Thanks

Comment: Is there a particular reason that you aren't able to build this dashboard within ServiceNow itself instead of outside? There are very easy options within ServiceNow for this exact purpose.

Comment: Hi Kirk,Thanks for your reply. I am looking to make a dashboard in a web . page. Like I have a URL, I will hit that and then will see some pie charts/graphs getting the info  from rest API(from ServiceNow). Can I make a Web app dashboard using service now?

Answer (score 1):

I would as Kirk suggested in the comments above, build this in Servicenow, however, if that is not an option this is another way.

Figure out the queries you need to get for those four data points you listed;
e.g. /cmn_company_list.do?sysparm_query=u_region=europe

Then make rest calls for each using the [Aggregate API](https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/jakarta-servicenow-platform/page/integrate/inbound-rest/reference/r_AggregateAPI-GET.html).

You may need to modify the [CORS][2] in Servicenow to allow your site to hit this endpoint, as well as use a service account.

Your code in Java would probably look something like;

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
  .url("https://something.service-now.com/api/now/stats/incident?sysparm_query=active%3Dtrue&sysparm_sum_fields=active")
  .get()
  .addHeader("content-type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("authorization", "Basic NeverGunnaGetIt")
  .addHeader("accept", "application/json")
  .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Which should result in something like this;

```
{
    "result": {
        "stats": {
            "sum": {
                "active": "6146"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jace. This part is done and ready. I am looking to make the front end (pie  charts and graphs) in the form of web page now. Can you please suggest something in this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest building this in ServiceNow rather than a separate web page, however if that's not an option you'll probably need to create charts with some sort of JavaScript library http://www.chartjs.org/

Take a look the documentation, but you could do something along these lines with the data you pull via REST. This is a bar chart, but that library has many chart options.

```
<script src="../lib/Chart.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
<script>
    var data = [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3, 12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3];
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: {
            labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            datasets: [{
                label: '# of Incidents per Month',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 220, 0.5)',
                data: data
            }]
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here you need to set the `data` to an array of data from REST.

[image]